# Image is overlaping on text

Tags: css

Code:

First div is containing image and image is overlapping on the contents of second div.

```
   <div>
    <img src="happy.jpg" style="height:50px;width:50px;border-radius:50%;float:left" /> alex is desperately looking for college and there are many more like here
    </div>

    <div id="progressbar">
    <label id="ProgressText">
        alex is still unhappy, step <label id="RemainingSteps">2</label> to go
    </label>
    <div id="progressFilled">

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want that image should not overlap the contents of second div. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <img src="happy.jpg" style="height:50px;width:50px;border-radius:50%;float:left" /> alex is desperately looking for college and there are many more like here
    </div>

    <div id="progressbar">
    <label id="ProgressText">
        alex is still unhappy, step <label id="RemainingSteps">2</label> to go
    </label>
    <div id="progressFilled">

    </div>
</div>
```

Add this to CSS

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The divs containing floated element should always be cleared so that the the height of the div adjusts according the the height of the maximum floated element inside. This is known as the clearfix hack. Refer this link for better understading. http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html If you are satisfied with the answer, I would appreciate if you select it as correct ans. Thanks :-)

Comment: @VinceCgto what`s the problem with this solution ? I have added the proper reason why this thing occurs.

Comment: @chiragswadia Well I've just always seen clearfixes with display: table as a dirtier hack than overflow: hidden (which is also cleaner). But yeah, you're right, it also works. Just one thing to note though, IE8 only partially supports pseudo-elements and IE7 doesn't support them at all.

Comment: @VinceCgto Yeah for IE browsers .clearfix { overflow: auto; zoom: 1; } should work I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set overflow to hidden.

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="happy.jpg" style="height:50px;width:50px;border-radius:50%;float:left" />
    alex is desperately looking for college and there are many more like here
</div>

<div id="progressbar">
    <label id="ProgressText">
        alex is still unhappy, step <label id="RemainingSteps">2</label> to go
    </label>
    <div id="progressFilled">
    </div>
</div>
```